# AlphaFold Multimer Colab, AMBER relaxation stuck at 83%

Tags: protein-database

I am running a heptameric sequence on AlphaFold Multimer Colab and using GPU A100, however, it has been stuck at 83% during AMBER relaxation for a while with WARNING:root:Warning: importing 'simtk.openmm' is deprecated.  Import 'openmm' instead.

Should I restart again (i have been running for around 5 hours) or just ignore the WARNING and let it keep running.